# How to get rid of the "Error in CPL_write_ogr" error when using "st_write" to export a sf object?

Tags: r, dplyr, r-sf, tidycensus, tigris

I'm trying to **intersect** two sf objects for the US (one at the township level and the other one at the census tract level). I'm getting both using `tigris` and `tidycensys`. My final goal is to have an unique ***sf object*** with information at the township level (with information from both the originals township and census tract level sf objects). And after I do this intersection, I want to export this sf object using `st_write` from the `sf` package. Here is the code I've used:

```
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(purrr)
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

##Data at township level 
#---------------------------#
MN_Township_SHP <- county_subdivisions("Minnesota", cb = TRUE)%>% st_transform(., crs=32618)
MN_Township_SHP$County <- substr(MN_Township_SHP$NAMELSADCO,1,nchar(MN_Township_SHP$NAMELSADCO)-7)
Dataset <- MN_Township_SHP

#Data at census tract level
#---------------------------#
Sys.getenv("CENSUS_API_KEY") 

my_vars <- 
  c(total_pop        = "B01003_001",
    race_denominator = "B02001_001", #Total
    white            = "B02001_002")
mn <- unique(fips_codes$state)[24]
MN_CensusTract_SHP <-map_df(mn, function(x) {
  get_acs(geography = "tract", 
          geometry = T, 
          variables = my_vars, 
          state = mn) })
MN_CensusTract_SHP <- MN_CensusTract_SHP %>% dplyr::select(-moe) 
Social_Dat <-
  MN_CensusTract_SHP %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = variable,
              values_from = c(estimate)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year=2021) %>% 
  dplyr::rename_all(funs(paste0("ACS_", .))) 
Social_Dat$ACS_year <- as.double(Social_Dat$ACS_year)
Social_Dat$ACS_GEOID <- as.double(Social_Dat$ACS_GEOID)
Social_Dat <- st_as_sf(Social_Dat, sf_column_name = 'ACS_geometry')%>% st_transform(., crs=32618)

#Intersection between township and census tract levels
#---------------------------#
final_df <- st_intersection(Dataset, Social_Dat, all=TRUE)

#Export sf object as shapefile 
#---------------------------#
st_write(final_df, "Input_Intermediate/final_df.shp",  delete_layer = TRUE)
```

However, when I run this final step, I get the following error:

**"Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :
Write error"**

Does anyone know how to solve this? I've tried so many ways that I found in google, but none of them worked for me. Many thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by doing the following:

1. Check possible variable names that may cause problems. I.e. I
   started only with the first 2 columns and then the following. One of
   them was giving me problems, so I changed the name.
2. Make sure the file name you are using to save your shapefile is short. In my case the error was because both the path+filename were too long.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function **st_collection_extract** and get only the polygon type from your geometry column, and then you can proceed and use **st_write** again.

```
df <- st_collection_extract(final_df, type = "POLYGON")
st_write(df, "Input_Intermediate/final_df.shp",  delete_layer = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, many thanks for your answer. I have been struggling with this issue with other databases, I tried your solution, but it didn't work out for the other cases. Do you have any idea of how can I solve this in a more general way? Many thanks in advance!